# vertically growing icicle

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

I made some "super" soap bubbles with my kids using the following ingredients:

- liquid dish soap
- tap water
- corn syrup

We left the solution out over night last night here in Maine and the temperature got down to −3 °C. This morning we found that the solution left in the lid had grown a vertical icicle.

There is no trickery here. I stepped outside and found these items as you see them below.

How could this icicle have formed?

[image: close-up view]

[image: context view]

Comment: That is a fairly unusual but previously documented formation called an [ice spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_spike). Curiously, it seems that details on how they form are still somewhat elusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much has to be a supercooling phenomenon.  [This page](https://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~smorris/edl/icespikes/icespikes.html) from the University of Toronto Physics department presents an explanation that I think fits the scenario in the question nicely.  The description and photos used suggest that this is likely the case for this question:

> The short explanation is this: as the ice freezes fast under
>   supercooled conditions, the surface can get covered except for a small
>   hole. Water expands when it freezes. As freezing continues, the
>   expanding ice under the surface forces the remaining water up through
>   the hole and it freezes around the edge forming a hollow spike.
>   Eventually, the whole thing freezes and the spike is left.
>
> A slightly longer explanation: the form of the ice crystals depends on
>   the cooling rate and hence on the degree of supercooling. Large
>   supercooling favors sheets which rapidly cover the surface, with some
>   sheets hanging down into the water like curtains. These crystallites
>   tend to join at 60 degrees and leave triangular holes in the surface.
>   Hence, spikes often have a triangular base. The sides of the spike are
>   sometimes a continuation of pre-existing subsurface crystallites, and
>   can extend from the surface at steep angles.

Notice the triangular shape at the base of the ice spike in the photos in the question, as is also mentioned in the description above.  The spike also appears to possibly have a hollow region through the center.  Additionally, the flexible plastic lid would allow for some pressure buildup before the release through some weak spot in the ice sheet.